# Flutter Material Icons is not showing correctly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, icons

Flutter material icons is not showing correctly as per the below photo, however other packages icons like awesomefonts and cupertinoicons shows without any issues
Screenshot_1659378460

[image]

also in pubspec.yaml this is set to true uses-material-design: true
and tried to make flutter clean and pub get with no effect at all.
and below is the flutter doctor summary

Comment: flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1826], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Comment: can you try with  building  on release mode

Comment: I'm just new to flutter so i tried flutter run -- release .. and here is the response Release mode is not supported by Android SDK built for x86.

Comment: does it happen for web and windows too?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no only for windows , I tried before the app on the web and the ions were working correctly.

Comment: Please do flutter clean , flutter pub upgrade and flutter pub get and try to run again

Comment: @HardikMehta tried this again and nothng changed

Comment: Please uninstall that app from device and try again